# error in conversion of keras model to tflite

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

I am using tensorflow version 2.3.1 and keras 2.4.3
I trained a keras model where after training I tried to convert it to tflite model using the following commands:

```
from keras.models import load_model
import tensorflow as tf

model = load_model("model.h5")
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(model)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-759f94851ff5> in <module>
----> 1 converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(model)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\lite.py in from_saved_model(cls, saved_model_dir, signature_keys, tags)
   1026
   1027     with context.eager_mode():
-> 1028       saved_model = _load(saved_model_dir, tags)
   1029     if not signature_keys:
   1030       signature_keys = saved_model.signatures

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py in load(export_dir, tags, options)
    601     ValueError: If `tags` don't match a MetaGraph in the SavedModel.
    602   """
--> 603   return load_internal(export_dir, tags, options)
    604
    605

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py in load_internal(export_dir, tags, options, loader_cls)
    612     tags = nest.flatten(tags)
    613   saved_model_proto, debug_info = (
--> 614       loader_impl.parse_saved_model_with_debug_info(export_dir))
    615
    616   if (len(saved_model_proto.meta_graphs) == 1 and

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\loader_impl.py in parse_saved_model_with_debug_info(export_dir)
     54     parsed. Missing graph debug info file is fine.
     55   """
---> 56   saved_model = _parse_saved_model(export_dir)
     57
     58   debug_info_path = os.path.join(

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\loader_impl.py in parse_saved_model(export_dir)
     84   # Build the path to the SavedModel in pbtxt format.
     85   path_to_pbtxt = os.path.join(
---> 86       compat.as_bytes(export_dir),
     87       compat.as_bytes(constants.SAVED_MODEL_FILENAME_PBTXT))
     88   # Build the path to the SavedModel in pb format.

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\compat.py in as_bytes(bytes_or_text, encoding)
     84     return bytes_or_text
     85   else:
---> 86     raise TypeError('Expected binary or unicode string, got %r' %
     87                     (bytes_or_text,))
     88

TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.Functional object at 0x0000022EC9005250>
```

I have no idea how to resolve this and why this has occured. Any suggestion to resolve this?

Comment: You should not mix keras and tensorflow in this way. If you want to use keras, you should use from ```tensorflow.keras import```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use converting method from `saved_model` protobuf with keras model. Your method is `tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
model = keras.models.load_model('path/to/location')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

See details [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert#convert_a_keras_model_)

Answer (score 0):

For me, shifting tensorflow version to 2.14.0 (older version) worked